# In Git How to know the list of conflicts (path) that have been resolved?

Tags: git, merge

Suppose I have many conflicts after merge and I have resolved some but I forget what they are, can I know which conflicts that have been resolved? Or can I know the initial conflicts (before resolving any one of them)?

git status doesn't work since the status of resolved conflict is "modified" and I can't identify them from other normal "modified" files.

Quite surprised that I can't find a solution for this from web :(

Comment: Why do you need that? Seems like a strange request... Also, do you want automatically resolved conflicts to be included in that "resolved" list?

Comment: @Roman Actually it happens when tens of conflicts occur and some of them are resolved and added. If someone wants to check what the resolved conflicts are, for example he wants to make sure the conflicts are resolved correctly, how does he know those resolved conflicts?

Answer (score -1):

You can do a `git show` on the merge commit.

Comment: Do you mean "git show  commit"? I tried, it doesn't help.

Comment: You can use `git log` to see the last commits and you'll see a commit id right to "commit". Then, you can do a `git show THE_COMMIT_ID`. It shows the diff between the commit and the previous commit.

Comment: But I am in the middle of resolving conflicts and actually I don't have a new commit yet. Even using git show commit, what I get are the whole diffs including "modified" files which are not exactly the same as "resolved" files.